# Reading a string expression with parameters and executing the expression as date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

I am trying to create dynamic code for date calculation in SQL stored procedures but am having problems executing string expressions and parameters as date expressions.

I want to hold  generic string expressions in a table that will create the dates according to the value of the parameters.

for example this is a generic expression :

```
DATEADD(@TimeResolution, -@IterationN, @CurrentCalc)
```

as you can see  these generic expressions are composed out of parameters to.

in the stored procedures I intend to declare the variables that are in the expression and assign values to them using a select statement from a different table.

the problem is that after deriving these string values and writing the expression it does not give me the date I want but fails.

so for example if I write the following code

> ```
> declare @Today date 
> declare @LastYear date
> set @Today = getdate()
>
> set @LastYear =  DATEADD(year, -1, @Today)
> select @Lastyear
> ```

it works fine and I will get last year's date.

but when I try something like this :

```
declare @Today date  
declare @LastYear date

declare @Timeresolution varchar(5) 
select @Timeresolution =  [Timeresolution] from dbo.mytable where rule_id=1//Timeresolution is a varchar column in my table holding the values 'year' or 'month'

declare Iteration int 
select @Iteration  =  [Iteration] from dbo.mytable where rule_id=1 //Iteration is a int column in my table holding the values  1 or 2, or 3

set @Today = getdate()

set @LastYear =  DATEADD(Timeresolution , -Iteration , @Today) 

select @Lastyear
```

this gives me a conversion error.

Is there a way to create such dynamic date expressions?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to use a variable for the interval in DATEADD, but you can do something like this:

```
IF @Timeresolution = 'year'
BEGIN
    SET @LastYear =  DATEADD(year, -@Iteration , @Today) 
END

IF @Timeresolution = 'month'
BEGIN
    SET @LastYear =  DATEADD(month, -@Iteration , @Today) 
END
```

Comment: thanks but. i was trying to avoid such if/case conditions since there could eventualy be more options for the variables.